# where to connect Potentiometer's pins

Tags: potentiometer, pins

I was looking for a circuit to give me 1hz pulse for a digital clock and i found [this circuit](http://www.electroschematics.com/4843/1-hz-pulse-generator/)

[image: Schematic]

Right now I have no idea how to connect potentiometer, i haven't used one before.
I'm trying to make this circuit

Where should i connect the pins in this circuit to make it work. 
here's the pin guide

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That circuit uses a potentiometer as a variable resistor. Connect the middle terminal of the potentiometer to one of the end terminals. Then use the two end terminals as the two terminals shown in the circuit.

Comment: ty i connect 1 to 2 and it worked